# Recursive squaring algorithm by reducing to squaring 5 numbers

Tags: recursive-algorithms

> *(c) Describe a recursive algorithm that squares any $n$-digit number in $O(n^{log_35})$ time, by reducing to squaring only five $(n/3+O(1))$-digit numbers.
> [Hint: What is $(a+b+c)^2+(a−b+c)^2$?]

I am currently studying the Toom-Cook algorithm which is highly related to this question. I came across a related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736216/recursive-squaring-algorithm-by-squaring-five-numbers) but could not understand it sufficiently. For example, why the form of $10^{2m}x+10^my+z$ and the discovery of the last missing square.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For $x,y,z$ you split your number into $3$ parts, each of them $m$ digits long.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Ok, I figured out the form part. Do you know about the last missing square?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's article on [Toom–Cook multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) has a nice explanation that doesn't involve guessing missing squares; let me simplify it for your case.

If you're writing your number as $10^{2m}a + 10^m b + c$ (essentially, breaking up the digits into three segments $a, b, c$) then you're writing your number as $p(10^m)$ where $p(x)$ is the quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$.

So the square of your number will be $p(10^m)^2$, which is the quartic polynomial $q(x) = p(x)^2 = (ax^2+bx+c)^2$ evaluated at $x=10^m$.

Now, we're going to try to find $q(x)$ in a different way. Specifically, we know the following:

- The constant term of $q(x)$ is $c^2$, or in other words $q(0)=p(0)^2=c^2$.
- The coefficient of $x^4$ in $q(x)$ is $a^2$, which Wikipedia thinks of as $q(\infty) = p(\infty)^2 = a^2$.
- $q(1) = p(1)^2 = (a+b+c)^2$.
- $q(-1) = p(-1)^2 = (a-b+c)^2$.
- $q(-2) = p(-2)^2 = (4a-2b+c)^2$.

The above squares are the five squares we're going to evaluate. Then, if $q(x) = q_4 x^4 + q_3 x^3 + q_2 x^2 + q_1 x + q_0$, we have a system of five equations in five variables:
\begin{align}
    q_0 &= c^2 \\
    q_4 &= a^2 \\
 q_4 + q_3 + q_2 + q_1 + q_0 &= (a+b+c)^2 \\
 q_4 - q_3 + q_2 - q_1 + q_0 &= (a-b+c)^2 \\
 16q_4 - 8q_3 + 4q_2 - 2q_1 + q_0 &= (4a-2b+c)^2
\end{align}
Solve these for the $q_i$'s and then evaluate $q(10^m)$ to find $(10^{2m}a+10^mb+c)^2$.

Comment: I think you got the (4a+2b+c)^2 part wrong, isn't it supposed to be (4a-2b+c)^2?

Comment: @AndrewKarasev It looks like I was inconsistent about using $q(2) = p(2)^2$ or $q(-2) = p(-2)^2$. Either one is fine if we use it consistently, but I think $-2$ is more likely to produce smaller numbers - a very tiny effect. I'll fix this, thanks for pointing it out.